# Repeat elements in pandas dataframe so equal number of each unique element

Tags: pandas, numpy, dataframe

I have a pandas dataframe with multiple different feature columns. I have one particular column which can take on a variety of integer value. I want to manipulate the dataframe in such a way that there is an equal number of each of these integer value.

Before;

```
df['key'] = [1,1,1,3,4,5,5]
```

After;

```
df['key'] = [1,1,1,3,3,3,4,4,4,5,5,5]
```

I want this to be applied to every key in the dataframe.

Comment: But that could lead to variable number of elements per key, right? Could you add a minimal case for two keys?

Comment: How do you want to duplicate existing rows?  Say for example I have 2 "1" keys and need to end up with 3 "1" keys.  Which "1" row gets duplicated?

Answer (score 0):

So here's an ugly way that I've coded up a solution, but I feel like it goes against the entire reason to use pandas dataframes.

```
for idx, i in enumerate(data['key'].value_counts()):
    if i == max(data['key'].value_counts()):
        pass
    else:
        scaling = (max(data['key'].value_counts()) // i) - 1
        data2 = pd.concat([data[data['key'] == idx]]*scaling, ignore_index=True)
        data = pd.concat([data, data2], ignore_index=True)
```

Comment: Does it handle multiple keys? Could you show a sample case run for the same?

Comment: I only want it to balance the dataframe according to the specified key.